# My stream keeps throwing Read/Write Timeout exceptions

Tags: c#, stream, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am parsing a PowerPoint presentation using Open Office SDK 2.0.  At one point in the program I'm passing a stream to a method that will return an image's MD5.  However, there seems to be a problem in the stream, before it even gets to my MD5 method.

Here's my code:

```
// Get image information here.
var blipRelId = blip.Embed;
var imagePart = (ImagePart)slidePart.GetPartById(blipRelId);
var imageFileName = imagePart.Uri.OriginalString;
var imageStream = imagePart.GetStream();
var imageMd5 = Hasher.CalculateStreamHash(imageStream);
```

In debug, before I let it drop into `Hasher.CalculateStreamHash`, I check the imageStream properties.  Immediately, I see that the ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout both have similar errors:

```
imageStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException
imageStream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException
```

Here's a picture of the properties that I"m seeing during debug, in case it helps:
[image]

This code is running over a PowerPoint presentation.  I'm wondering if the fact that it's zipped (a PowerPoint presentation is basically just a zipped up file) is the reason I'm seeing those timeout errors?

UPDATE:  I tried taking the stream, getting the image and converting it to a byte array and sending that to the MD5 method as a memory stream, but I still get those same errors in the Read/Write Timeout properties of the stream.  Here's the code as it is now:

```
// Get image information here.
var blipRelId = blip.Embed;
var imagePart = (ImagePart)slidePart.GetPartById(blipRelId);
var imageFileName = imagePart.Uri.OriginalString;
var imageStream = imagePart.GetStream();

// Convert image to memory stream
var img = Image.FromStream(imageStream);
var imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(this.imageToByteArray(img));
var imageMd5 = Hasher.CalculateStreamHash(imageMemoryStream);
```

For clarity, here's the signature for the CalculateStreamHash method:

```
public static string CalculateStreamHash([NotNull] Stream stream)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mischief managed!  I was able to overcome this problem by using a BufferedStream and adding an overloaded method to my MD5 method that accepted a BufferedStream as a parameter:

```
// Get image information here.
var blipRelId = blip.Embed;
var imagePart = (ImagePart)slidePart.GetPartById(blipRelId);
var imageFileName = imagePart.Uri.OriginalString;

// Convert image to buffered stream
var imageBufferedStream = new BufferedStream(imagePart.GetStream());
var imageMd5 = Hasher.CalculateStreamHash(imageBufferedStream);
```

...and:

```
public static string CalculateStreamHash([NotNull] BufferedStream bufferedStream)
```